# numpy insert an element keeping number of array dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, append

I have a numpy array like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

and I want to append an element `[100, 101, 102]` to the array like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [100, 101, 102]]
```

I tried `numpy.append` but it creates a 1D array with all the elements. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `axis` when using `np.append` and also the value needs to have the correct shape; The following works:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
b = [100, 101, 102]

np.append(a, [b], axis=0)
#array([[  1,   2,   3],
#       [  1,   2,   4],
#       [100, 101, 102]])
```

If you have lists:

```
a.append(b)
np.array(a)
```

Should be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Or with [***np.vstack(tup)***](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) routine:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]])
arr = np.vstack((arr, [100, 101, 102]))
print(arr)
```

The output:

```
[[  1   2   3]
 [  1   2   4]
 [100 101 102]]
```